# What is clearing and setting bits used for and why is it useful?

Tags: c++

```
    if (mode) 
        CLRBITS(field->flag, UFMODE_GREY);
    else 
        SETBITS(field->flag, UFMODE_GREY);
```

`CLRBITS` and `SETBITS` are just macros that are set to clear and set bits using the appropriate bitwise operations. `UFMODE_GREY` is also a macro that equates to `0x0200`.

Comment: Please answer yourself (you have more insight)

Comment: Because whoever designed the `field->flag` wanted the bits set or cleared.

Comment: What is your question? Do you wonder why they bothered to use a macro? Probably to make it more readable for natural-language-oriented people, who can more easily tell the intention is to set something to the value for grey on and off, rather than thinking about it in terms of bitwise operations and values.

Comment: "Why are bits useful" is really something a textbook or tutorial should explain to you.  There's just too much to describe.

Answer (score 1):

Bits are used to compress a set of boolean flags into a smaller space.  In C and C++ the style you cited is generally used for APIs targeting multiple compilers and systems which may choose to pack structures with boolean flags differently.  The CLRBITS and SETBITS macros are to provide clearer statement of what is to be achieved.  This is a lot less messy than the following would be:

```
if( mode ){
  field->flag = field->flag & ~0x200;
}else {
  field->flag = field->flag | 0x200;
}
```

Comment: That's a good start, although bits set in that way don't have to be *boolean flags* or *compressed*.

Comment: You are **correct** as `field->flag` could be used as an `int`, `char`, etc.  However the above usage idiomatically implies `field->flag` is an array of boolean flags.  I've always thought of this as a _compressed_ array of boolean flags due to many environments alias `bool` and `boolean` as an integer type, thus wasting `sizeof(int)-1` of space.  Do you have a better term I could use in the above answer?

Comment: Considering that it's a closed question, I'd leave it alone.  Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Okay all your "constructive" criticism is greatly appreciated...nobody told me what clearing and setting bits is useful for. flag is declared as a 'short', not a boolean